# How to carry out multivariable logistic regression using a binary target variable in python?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter, logistic-regression, sklearn-pandas

I have data which looks something like this (there are 10,000 rows in the actual data):

|  | Gender | Parent | Employment | Age Range | Discount? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Female | Yes | Full-time | 30-39 | No |
| 1 | Male | No | Part-time | 40-49 | Yes |
| 2 | Other | Yes | Full-time | 30-39 | No |
| 3 | Female | Yes | Unemployed | 30-49 | Yes |
| 4 | Male | Yes | Part-time | 40-49 | Yes |
| 5 | Female | No | Full-time | 20-29 | No |
| 6 | Male | Yes | Part-time | 50-59 | Yes |
| 7 | Female | No | Unemployed | 30-39 | No |

I was hoping to create a multi-variable binary logistic regression using this data so that I can predict whether or not a client uses a discount ('Yes' or 'No') based on the 'Gender', 'Parent', 'Employment' and 'Age Range' variables, however wasn't sure how to go about this in python. I tried to apply this but it did not work for me:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X = Customer_table[['Gender','Parent','Employment','Age Range']]
y = Customer_table['Discount?']

X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test= train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.25,random_state=0)
logistic_regression= LogisticRegression()

logistic_regression.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred=logistic_regression.predict(X_test)
```

I'm not very sure how to create a logistic regression using multiple string variables as X and a binary column 'Discount' for Y to predict. Is someone able to guide me on this?

Comment: sklearn has a [logistic regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) class

Answer (score 0):

You would have to transition those categorical values to dummy or numerical ones. So in the case of gender, changing female to 1, male to 0. In the case of your dependent variable, Yes being 1 and No being 0. Doing that for every string value item should return your desired result.